# Rack: Multiple session cookies for a single rack application

Tags: ruby, rack

How can one interact with multiple sessions cookies (for different path or domains) in a single rack application?

For example, considering the following application using 3 locations:

- www.my-app.net => main app
- www.my-app.net/app_a => sub app A
- app_b.my_app.net/ => sub app B

Should be able to interact with 3 sessions cookies:

- domain=www.my-app.net; path=/;
- domain=www.my-app.net; path=/app_a;
- domain=app_b.my-app.net/; path=/;

Rack::Session::Cookie seemed to be a good choice, but as a middleware the session cookie has to be set in config.ru and seems to be limited to one session cookie per rack application.

In this special case, the main rack application point is to easily add sub applications, so dividing the application in multiple rack application to use Rack::Session::Cookie is not a viable solution.

The ideal would be a way to interact freely with multiple session cookies from inside the rack application code.

For now, I am considering:

- writing a middleware that allow interaction with multiple session cookies
- use CGI::Cookie to implement a custom session cookie management inside the application

But both are quite tedious so I was wondering if there was a simpler way to achieve this functionality.

Thanks in advance for any advice or suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone run with the same needs, I found that making a class to managing sessions inside the application was the easiest way to go.

Rack::Utils have 2 nice shortcuts, [Rack::Utils.set_cookie_header!](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/Rack/Utils#set_cookie_header!-class_method) and [Utils.delete_cookie_header!](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/Rack/Utils.delete_cookie_header!) that can really make the things easier when dealing with cookies.

I am saving the sessions in the database  used my application, but it should be trivial to support another back-end.

As a side note, a few considerations I came with:

- To be sure to the name of the cookie is valid, I am using a sha-1 of the sub-application name for that purpose.
- [SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/securerandom/1.9.2/SecureRandom) is useful for generating session key.
- Sessions cleaning and refreshing has to be implemented manually.

---

## Sample code

The class managing the cookies, the commit function set and delete the cookies to rack.

```
class Framework::Response::Cookies

  def set( params )
    @cookies[params.delete( :name )] = params
  end

  def remove( params )
    @remove_cookies[params.delete( :name )] = params
  end

  def commit( headers )
    @cookies.each_pair do |name, params|
      Rack::Utils.set_cookie_header!( headers, name, params )
    end
    @remove_cookies.each_pair do |name, params|
      Rack::Utils.delete_cookie_header!( headers, name, params )
    end
  end

end
```

The class managing the session (using Mongo as a backend):

```
class Database::Mongo::Session < Session

  def save
    expire = Time.now + @session_ttl
    @framework.content.db.find_and_modify( self.collection_name, { 
      :query => { :name => @session_name, :id => @session_id }, 
      :update => { :expire => expire, :name => @session_name, :id => @new_session_id || @session_id , :variables => @variables.to_hash },
      :upsert => true 
    })
    @framework.response.cookies.set( 
      :name => @session_name,
      :value => @new_session_id || @session_id,
      :path => @framework.applications.active.active_request['path'],
      :domain => @framework.applications.active.active_request['host'],
      :httponly => true  
    )
  end

  def delete
    @framework.content.db.remove( self.collection_name, { :id => @session_id } )
    @framework.response.cookies.remove( :name => @session_name )
  end

end
```

Each time `@framework.response.cookies.set` is called, it pushes a cookie data to the `Framework::Response::Cookies` class `@cookies` variable.

Before serving the response, a call to `Framework::Response::Cookies.commit` commit the cookies using `Rack::Utils`.

Comment: Could you add some detail on how you managed multiple cookies inside a single Rack application? If I call `use Rack::Session::Cookie` I get a cookie for the current session. But it seems like calling it again, overwrites the old cookie with a new one (I can't access the old one anymore)? Should I create multiple classes and call "use" within each to get different cookies? All input/code samples appreciated!

Comment: @SteveMidgley I added some sample code, the code is little old so there is maybe a better way to do it with newer versions of rack. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Eric - I think I got my problem solved by calling `response.set_cookie(key, string)` - this adds a new cookie key-value set based on the cookie config parameters set when enabling cookies. Thanks again for following up!